# How to redirect any request to a specific page if the visitor was using a certain name?

Tags: nginx

How can I get visitors redirected to a specific html page if the name used to resolve the server address was a specific one? I tried

```
if ($http_host ~ /forbiddenname/)
{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /updateyourlinks.html break;
}
```

inside the `Server` section, but doesn't work...

Comment: This question may be better quited for StackOverflow

Comment: I asked also on Pro Webmaster... and was thinking about Server Fault, but why Stack Overflow? That's for programming questions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that I should use instead of an `if` a virtual host... what I've added to nginx configuration is another server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.badname.com;
    rewrite ^ http://goodname.com/updateyourlinks.html;
}
```

and this apparently works